# How to pass parameters to xunit unit tests ran through the console runner?

Tags: xunit

The NUnit console runner has the `-p` command line parameter which is used to pass parameters to the test.

It seems that XUnit suggests us to drop dead in this respect or read the parameters from the environment.

Do I understand it correctly or am I missing anything? If this is correct, what is the motivation?

Comment: Amazing, nobody knows.